# An efficient way to assign value based on a certain value in another row and column within the same group

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with some household survey data using Pandas. It is a common task that I need to create a new column that contains information for some other specific household member.

To be concrete, here is a minimum example of what the data could look like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'hhid':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                 'pid':[1,2,3,1,2,1,3,5,6],
                 'edu':[4,2,3,4,5,3,4,6,3]})
```

`hhid` is household id; `pid` is personal id within the household;
`edu` is some information about the person `pid`.

An example of the kind of thing I need to do is as follows:

I want to generate a new column that shows the `edu` of household member with `pid` 2 if this row has `pid` equals to 1 and shows the `edu` of household member with `pid` 1 if this row has `pid` equals to 2. If the `pid` is neither 1 or 2, then the value takes `NaN`. (So, this can be imagined as a column with spouse's education level.)

Note that it is possible that not each `hhid` is matched with a `pid` of 1 or 2. (hhid=3 gives an example of not having pid=2.) The output for this artificial example should be

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'hhid':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                 'pid':[1,2,3,1,2,1,3,5,6],
                 'edu':[4,2,3,4,5,3,4,6,3]},
                 'sp_edu':[2,4,NAN,5,4,NAN,NAN,NAN,NAN])
```

Since I need to do this kind of manipulations pretty often and sometimes the data can be large. I hope that someone can show me an efficient way of doing this.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, would it not be better to have a dataframe with one row for each `hhid` and colums 1,2,3,... for each household members whose values come from `edu`? To me it sounds like this would be cleaner...

Comment: what is your expected out put